# Possibility of rearrangements in combinations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

OK, this may sound a rookie question, but recently I came across permutations and combinations and have a doubt.

Suppose we have, 4 white and 8 Black balls. Then number of ways of selecting 2 White and 3 Black is given by

4c2 × 8c3

but isn't this the number of ways of selecting those balls, what about the possible rearrangements,

Hence, a factor of 5!/(2!3!) Should be multiplied??

Or obviously (according to me)
We should take permutations instead of combinations to find the number of possible ways??

Comment: It all depends on what is being asked.  Are the balls of a fixed color distinguished in some way?  Are you taking into account the order of the selection?  These things need to be specified before you can be sure which answer is intended.

Comment: $$\left[\binom{4}{2} \times \binom{8}{3}\right] \times \binom{5}{2}$$ is correct.  The 3rd factor can be explained by reasoning that once the $2$-White, $3$-Black balls are chosen, you then have to choose $2$ of the $5$ *ordering* *positions* (i.e. 1st, 2nd, ..., 5th) for the $2$ White balls to occur in.

Answer (score 2):

The "number of ways of selecting 2 White and 3 Black balls" is not a precise question.  There are (at least) three things that must be stated in order for an answer to be possible.

- Are all four white balls identical, or are they different (for example they are numbered $1$ to $4$)?  Same for black.
- Is it permitted to choose the same ball more than once?  (For example, choose a ball, write down its colour, put it back and choose again.)
- Is the order of choices important?

Without this information, the question cannot be answered.

**Example 1**.  All the white balls are identical, same for black, and order of choices does not matter.  In this case, saying that you have $2$ white balls and $3$ black describes the situation completely, so answer: there is only $1$ way to do it.

**Example 2**.  All white balls are identical, same for black, order does matter.  Then the question is the same as asking, if you have $2$ white and $3$ black, how many ways to order them?  Answer: there are $5$ locations and you have to choose $2$ of them for the white balls.  **Note carefully** that we are now choosing places, not balls.  So: can we choose the same place twice? - no, that would mean putting two white balls in the same place.  Is the order of choices important? - no, the balls are identical, so for example putting white balls in places $1$ and $4$ is the same as putting them in places $4$ and $1$ - so this is a combinations problem and the answer is $C(5,2)$.

**Example 3**.  All balls are different, same ball cannot be chosen more than once, order is important.  It is best to set out the solution step by step.

- Choose places for the white balls - $C(5,2)$ ways as in example $2$.
- Choose which white balls (choose $2$ from $4$, order matters) - $P(4,2)$ ways.
- Choose which black balls - similarly, $P(8,3)$ ways.

Final answer: $C(5,2)P(4,2)P(8,3)$.